# Drawing A Hasse Diagram Using Letters

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

I am trying to draw a Hasse diagram but using letters instead of numbers. The problem is below:

The domain is $\{a, b, c, d, e, f\}$. The relation is the set:
$\{ (b, e), (b, d), (c, a), (c, f), (a, f), (a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (d, d), (e, e), (f, f) \}$

The problem that I am having is where to put the letters on the diagram since I know that in Hasse diagrams, some elements have higher importance than others. So my question is how would I go about starting this Hasse diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that an ordered pair $(b, e)$ means that $b \leqslant e$. If it in fact means $b \geqslant e$, just draw the Hasse diagram I'm describing and turn it upside down :-)

To start, I'll just make a quick table of who's "less than" whom.

\begin{array}{l|l}
a & f\\
b & d, e\\
c & a, f\\
d & \\
e & \\
f & \\
\end{array}

where the $b$ row corresponds to the fact that $b \leqslant d$ and $b \leqslant e$. Because partial orders are reflexive, I haven't bothered to list $x \leqslant x$, since we know that to be the case and displaying it only makes the relevant information less visible.

Taking $d$ as an example, if $d \leq y$, then $y = d$; there's nothing above $d$ in the Hasse diagram. All of $d, e$, and $f$ are in top of the Hasse diagram; they're never below anything. A poset can have several maximal elements, and they need not be on the same "level" (and that's the case here).

Oppositely, take $b$. If $x \leqslant b$, then $x = b$; nothing is below $b$ (or $c$) in the Hasse diagram. They're the minimal elements, and are drawn at the same "level."

That leaves only $a$, who is both above $c$, and below $f$; we have $c \leqslant a \leqslant f$.

Try and see if you can work something out here. Below I'll list a couple more hints, that should verify if you're right or not (but don't look until you try!).

> The Hasse diagram here will be disconnected. One piece will just be a straight "line" for the $c \leqslant a \leqslant f$ (with $c$ at the bottom). The other piece will be a kind of V shape, with $b$ at the bottom and $e, d$ at the top.

Comment: My general strategy was to figure out which elements are maximal, and which are minimal. Then you can figure out who's directly below ("is covered by") the maximal elements, and directly above ("covers") the minimal elements, working your way toward the middle (or start at the top/bottom and only go in one direction). But here, almost everything was maximal or minimal, there wasn't a lot of meeting in the middle.